# Permission for private file to anonymous

Tags: 8, users, files

I have an ad content type, with a file field that is in a private directory when saving the node.

Ads and their files are only accesible for authenticated users.

I wish I could allow anonymous users to see ads and their files that are promoted.

I use content_access module
[image]

I want programmaticly, change acces control foreach ads who is promoted and I don't how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to check out the [Private Files Download Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) module which may provide exactly the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried the module and the problem is that the files of the directory are accesible by url directly.